# JavaScript onClick: First action executed only after full sequence of functions is done

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have an onClick() event that executes a function that contains an action and a second function.

```
function colorcodeSelectedElement()
{
    document.getElementById("something").style.border="2px solid red";
    executeAnotherFunction();
}
```

If I click the item, the red border occurs only after second function if finished. If this second function takes 30 seconds, the red border occurs after 30 seconds.
I would like to add some hourglas in case the second function takes longer...but I struggle due to the fact that, whatever UI element I draw or repaint, it always gets executed AFTER second function...which makes a "please wait" useless.

How do I get the first UI action executed immediately on onClick...before the second function starts?

Comment: It *does* execute; the UI doesn't get a chance to show the results.  Try putting the second function on as short a timer as possible.

Answer (score 0):

the color should change to red based on what you have written.

here is an example using promise to delay executeAnotherFunction  : https://jsitor.com/y7x1TWSVJ

but as you see the color change before executeAnotherFunction  is finished

Answer (score 0):

Using a timer works but it is best to use `async` if possible, like so:

```js
async function colorcodeSelectedElement(){
    //waits until the code in the brackets has finished before calling executeAnotherFunction
    await (document.getElementById("something").style.border="2px solid red");
    executeAnotherFunction();
}
```

Here is an example of it in use https://codepen.io/codedevlo/pen/PoEEarO.

[async reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score -1):

The Timer does the trick...!!

```
function colorcodeSelectedElement()
{
    document.getElementById("something").style.border="2px solid red";
    setTimeout (function() {executeAnotherFunction();},100);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).